# SQL find unique foreign keys in child table

Tags: sql

I have following table:

```
Participant{
participant_id (primary key),
channel_id(foreign key),
address_1 varchar,
address_2 varchar,
address_3 varchar,
}
```

And I need select channel_ids (to find then channels) where particular addresses present. Please note that there might me multiple participants in the same channel.

**EDIT:**
Lets assume there are 4 participants:

```
Participant 1{
1, 
1, 
'address1',
null,
null
}

Participant 2{
2, 
1, 
null,
'address_2_o',
null
}

Participant 3{
3, 
1, 
null,
null,
'ole'
}

Participant 4{
4, 
2, 
null,
null,
'ole'
}
```

And if I want to make a query to select channel sids where participants have address_1 = 'address1' and address_3 = 'ole' it should return me one channel id = 1.

Comment: What is it that you are stuck on? Please share sample data, code and expected output.

Comment: updated example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select p.channel_id
from Participant p
group by p.channel_id
having sum(case when address_1 = 'address1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when address_3 = 'ole' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Participant 3 and Participant 4 have the same address. This query will return 2 channels: 1,2

```
select distinct channel_id
from Participant
where isnull(address_1,'')='address1'
or isnull(address_3,'')='ole'
```

Comment: expected result is only channel 1 since both participants with required addresses are in it. Channel 2 doesn't have participant with address1

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear, do you need a list of unique channel IDs for a specific address?

```
select distinct channel_id
from Participant
where address_1='<address1>'
and address_2='<address2>'
...
```

Comment: probably I missed example - I updated my question. Problem with your answer that single participant should have both addresses but in my case addresses might be in different participants.

Comment: but the trick is that particular channel should have participants where listed addresses are present.